# printf("Enter 'a' : "); runs 2 times after 1st loop

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
     char a = 'v';

     for (int i = 0; a != 'x'; ) 
     {        
         printf("Enter 'a' : "); 
         scanf("%c",&a);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

I ran it and gave input **k**. When I hit enter after this , why my `printf` runs **2 times** when loop runs second times?

Comment: There is no loop iteration condition.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai: `a != 'x'` is the exit condition; there is no loop *increment*

Comment: Hmmm, I messed up the terms...

Comment: `int i = 0;` is redundant and can be dropped: `for (;a != 'x';) {...}` or, better, `while (a != 'x') {...}`

Comment: If I input 'spacebar' multiple times and hit enter , "Enter 'a' : " is printed out as many times as I input 'spacebar'. why?

Comment: @user10056563: you read *char*s, not *string*s: `scanf("%c",&a);` reads single char, you have `"Enter 'a' : "` displayed, then scanf("%c",&a);` reads another char etc.

Comment: This seems to be a buffer issue of `scanf`, it is loaded with *the character entered followed by `\n`*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko But if i read some character and hit enter i get  "Enter 'a' : "  "Enter 'a' : "    . Why 2 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this behaviour, we can simulate step-by-step the execution.

```
printf("Enter 'a' : "); 
scanf("%c",&a); // User type in example 'a' and presses enter.
```

`scanf` "bufferize" `a\n` and places in `a` the value `'a'`

The loop condition isn't satisfied, since `'a' == 'x'` is `false`

```
printf("Enter 'a' : ");
scanf("%c",&a); // The buffer still contains `'\n'`
```

Since the buffer still contains unconsumed data, the next character (`'\n'`) is placed in `a` and the loop continues.

The loop condition isn't satisfied, since `'\n' == 'x'` is `false`

```
printf("Enter 'a' : ");
scanf("%c",&a); // The buffer is empty now.
```

This gives you the illusion that the loop displays twice the `printf`, but in fact, the `scanf` kept reading the buffer without the need of user input.

If you enter more characters, in example `qwerty`, `"Enter 'a' : "` will be displayed 7 times, because `"qwerty"` contains 6 characters + `'\n'`

---

Note that using `while (a != 'x')` would suit better your needs than `for (int i = 0; a != 'x'; )`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `scanf` and `%c`, it reads *any* character -- including the newline character you get when you press the ENTER key.

So if you run the program and type

```
a <Return>
```

you take two trips through the loop: one to read the `'a'` and one to read the `'\n'`.  If you type

```
<Space> <Space> a <Return>
```

it makes four trips through the loop.  And if you type

```
x <Return>
```

it only makes one trip through the loop, because it notices you typed the `'x'`, and exits.

Things will become a little more clear if you print out each character you receive:

```
for (int i = 0; a != 'x'; )
{
    printf("Enter 'a' : ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("you typed %d =  %c\n", a, a);
}
```

When you see it printing

```
 you typed 10 =
```

that's one of the newlines.  (The value of `'\n'` is 10 in ASCII.)

I said that `%c` reads *any* character -- but that's somewhat unusual.  Most of `scanf`'s other format specifiers -- `%d`, `%f`, `%s`, etc. -- skip over "whitespace" -- that is, spaces, tabs, newlines, and a few others.  But `%c` does not skip over those, because its job is to read exactly one character, and someone thought you might want to use it to read whitespace characters, too.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this loop

```
for (int i = 0; a != 'x'; )
```

does not make sense at least because the variable `i` is not used within the loop.

Also this prompt

```
printf("Enter 'a' : ");
```

only confuses users. You are asking the user to enter the character `'a'` while the loop stops when the character `'x'` is entered.

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

reads all characters including white-space characters. It is the reason why the loop iterates one more. You have to write

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
        ^^^
```

In this case white spaces will be skipped.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter a character ('x' - exit): " );
    } while ( scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1 && c != 'x' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why giving a space before %c avoids the problem?

Comment: Because it consumes first a *whitespace* (in your case, `'\n'`)

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming. But why is scanf compared to 1 in 'while'?

Comment: @user10056563 It means that the function read successfully one item. Take into account that the user can interrupt the input. In this case the function will return EOF.